# Objects Overwritten Despite Different Keys

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Hoping someone here can illuminate this situation for me - perhaps I'm missing something simple.

I have a process set-up whereby my app fetches a pre-signed URL from an S3 bucket in order to upload one or more images. When the image is uploaded, a Lambda function written on top of the SDK is triggered. This lambda should resize the image into 3 different sizes, and assign them keys / place them into a "folder" like so: photos/000/123/456/medium/image.jpg, photos/000/123/456/large/image.jpg, photos/000/123/456/original/image.jpg.

Unfortunately, with each iteration, the previous object is overwritten so that photos/000/123/456/ ends up containing only original/image.jpg. I was under the impression that all three, since they are different keys, would be saved and not overwrite each other. This appears not to be the case? Code sample below (note that originally the images were being placed into their destination bucket via loop; in the process of breaking the code down it has become slightly messy, but it works and the results are the same with or without a loop):

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var path = require('path');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm')
            .subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.
var util = require('util');

var max_width  = 20;
var max_height = 20;

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  // Read options from the event.
  console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
  var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
  var dstBucket = srcBucket;
  var dstKey    = srcKey.replace('originals', 'assets');
  var extension = path.extname(dstKey);
  var filename  = path.basename(dstKey, extension);
  var directory = path.dirname(dstKey);
  // dstKey = directory + '/' + filename + extension;
  // var sub_folders = ['original', 'large', 'medium', 'thumb']


    //  LARGE image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    dstKey = directory + '/' + 'large' + '/' + filename + extension;
    max_width  = 600;
    max_height = 600;
    async.waterfall([
      function download(next) {
        // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
        s3.getObject({
            Bucket: srcBucket,
            Key: srcKey
          },
          next);
        },
      function transform(response, next) {
        gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
          // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
          var scalingFactor = Math.min(
            max_width / size.width,
            max_height / size.height
          );
          var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
          var height = scalingFactor * size.height;
          // var height = scalingFactor * size.height;
          // Transform the image buffer in memory.
          this.resize(width, height)
            .toBuffer(null, function(err, buffer) {
              if (err) {
                next(err);
              } else {
                next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
              }
            });
        });
      },
      function upload(contentType, data, next) {
        // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: dstBucket,
            Key: dstKey,
            Body: data,
            ContentType: contentType
          },
          next);
        }
      ], function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(
            'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
            ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
            ' due to an error: ' + err
          );
        } else {
          console.log(
            'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
            ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
          );
        }

        context.done();
      }
    );


    // MEDIUM download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    dstKey = directory + '/' + 'medium' + '/' + filename + extension;
    max_width  = 600;
    max_height = 600;
    async.waterfall([
      function download(next) {
        // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
        s3.getObject({
            Bucket: srcBucket,
            Key: srcKey
          },
          next);
        },
      function transform(response, next) {
        gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
          // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
          var scalingFactor = Math.min(
            max_width / size.width,
            max_height / size.height
          );
          var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
          var height = scalingFactor * size.height;
          // var height = scalingFactor * size.height;
          // Transform the image buffer in memory.
          this.resize(width, height)
            .toBuffer(null, function(err, buffer) {
              if (err) {
                next(err);
              } else {
                next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
              }
            });
        });
      },
      function upload(contentType, data, next) {
        // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: dstBucket,
            Key: dstKey,
            Body: data,
            ContentType: contentType
          },
          next);
        },

      function transform(response, next) {
        gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
          // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
          var scalingFactor = Math.min(
            330 / size.width,
            330 / size.height
          );
          var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
          var height = scalingFactor * size.height;
          // var height = scalingFactor * size.height;
          // Transform the image buffer in memory.
          this.resize(width, height)
            .toBuffer(null, function(err, buffer) {
              if (err) {
                next(err);
              } else {
                next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
              }
            });
        });
      },
      function upload(contentType, data, next) {
        // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: dstBucket,
            Key: directory + '/' + 'medium' + '/' + filename + extension,
            Body: data,
            ContentType: contentType
          },
          next);
        }
      ], function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(
            'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
            ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
            ' due to an error: ' + err
          );
        } else {
          console.log(
            'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
            ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
          );
        }

        context.done();
      }
    );    


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, your code is not actually written to do what you intended.

`async.waterfall( ... );` does not block the surrounding program flow.  It returns almost immediately -- I'm not certain whether this occurs immediately after or immediately before the *first* nested function starts, but it is one of those two -- and the precise timing is not terribly important in the current discussion, because either way, it returns very quickly and execution proceeds with whatever is below it.

You are thus overwriting the value of `dstKey` and other variables in memory multiple times *before* your waterfall-nested functions actually get around to using the values of the variables... and they will see the *current* value.  The value of `dstKey` is sitting at its value from the *final* assignment before any of the resize operations finish and because of this, *you* are overwriting the object because you are always using the last value of `dstKey`.

These waterfalls are all executing uncoordinated, in parallel.  That is how asynchronous functions operate.  They can't block execution -- that would also block the event loop.

Log the values of the variables inside the various functions (and context of where you are, such as before calling the s3 upload function) and you should be able to see this in action.

Comment: Quite correct. This is what comes of approaching JS on anything but JS' terms. :) Appreciate the feedback, thank you.